# How to use a variable to find a matching key in a dictionary and return the value?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get the value from the key in my dictionary. I am trying to match known fingerprints of host devices and return the associated value. I believe it is not properly interperting the variable since there is a slash in it. The code is below.

```
fingerprints = {
    'AAAABBBB': 'host1',
    'AAAA/CCC': 'tester',
    'AAAADDDD': 'plif'
    }

host_fingerprint = os.system("ssh-keyscan <ip of target> 2>&1 | grep ed25519 | cut -d ' ' -f 3")
    print(host_fingerprint)
    print(fingerprints['AAAA/CCC'])
    print(fingerprints[host_fingerprint])
```

The first 2 print statements work as expected and the output of host_fingprint is AAAA/CCC. How can I properly use the variable to print the value in the dictionary?

When trying with subprocess.check_output, I am getting

```
Getting error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/starkiller/starkiller.py", line 50, in <module>
    main()
  File "~/starkiller/starkiller.py", line 45, in main
    match_users()
  File "~/starkiller/starkiller.py", line 37, in match_users
    host_fingerprint = subprocess.check_output("ssh-keyscan 10.10.10.30 2>&1 | grep ed25519 | cut -d ' ' -f 3")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 424, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 505, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1823, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "ssh-keyscan <target IP> 2>&1 | grep ed25519 | cut -d ' ' -f 3"
```

What finally ended up working was to add a couple pieces to the end of the subprocess and then strip the newline charachter.

```
keyscan = subprocess.check_output(["ssh-keyscan <target IP> 2>&1 | grep ed25519 | cut -d ' ' -f 3"], shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
    host_fingerprint = keyscan.strip()
```

Comment: What is the value of `host_fingerprint`? Is it in the dictionary?

Comment: Try to add `.strip()` to the end of `host_fingerprint = os.system("...")`.

Comment: host_fingerprint is AAAA/CCC and verified with a print statement. it is also in the dictionary as AAAA/CCC: tester

Comment: I don't see how that can possibly work.  `os.system` does not return the stdout of the process.  It returns the process' numeric exit code, probably 0 in this case.  Try using `subprocess.check_output` instead.

Comment: You are SEEING the host fingerprint on your terminal, but that's `cut` writing to stdout.  I presume that is immediately followed by a `0`; that's your `host_fingerprint` variable.

Comment: @TimRoberts That definately makes sense, not sure how the variable is printing properly though when I print the host_fingerprint though. I added the latest error when trying with subprocess. I saw something in my searching about subprocess.PIPE, not sure if I could use that instead of the actual pipe

Comment: Finally got it, what finally ended up working will be in my original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are being fooled into thinking that worked by the way things print on the terminal, but `os.system` does not return a string.  The command you execute just prints its normal output directly to stdout, then `os.system` returns the numeric exit code (0).

This should work:

```
fingerprints = {
    'AAAABBBB': 'host1',
    'AAAA/CCC': 'tester',
    'AAAADDDD': 'plif'
    }

host_fingerprint = subprocess.check_output("ssh-keyscan <ip of target> 2>&1 | grep ed25519 | cut -d ' ' -f 3")
print(host_fingerprint)
print(fingerprints['AAAA/CCC'])
print(fingerprints[host_fingerprint])
```